# Mount FAT32 loopback as writeable

Tags: linux, mount, loopback

I'm trying to fix a corrupted FAT32 partition. The partition is working again, but I want to delete the remaining files containing wrong names and similar.

I have a full dump of the SD-card in question, but even if I try to mount it as writable, it's still read-only:

```
# losetup -o 4194304 /dev/loop0 sdcard.img
# mount -o rw,loop /dev/loop0 /mnt/sdcard
# cd /mnt/sdcard/Android/data
# rm $'\265'LI@BO\~1.APP
rm: cannot remove '\265LI@BO~1.APP': Read-only file system
```

Any idea how I can mount it as writable?

EDIT:

The following doesn't work either

```
mount -t vfat -o rw,offset=4194304,utf8,umask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 sdcard.img /mnt/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you need to mount it as a fat32 filesystem (`-t vfat` option to `mount`) to access the **files** in it (otherwise how do you know what the data in it represents?)

The filesystem also has to be fixed otherwise it will be automatically switched to read-only mode whenever a corruption is detected during accesses - to prevent further corruption (happens for any filesystem, not only for fat32).

If that's the case you need to unmount it and fix it (using fsck.vfat in linux or scandisk in windows). Make a copy beforehand.

Comment: That doesn't work either - see my update to my question. The partition is mounted correctly, and I can browse files as normal. The thing is that it's read-only although all files looks writable.

Comment: googling shows lots of such cases caused by corrupted filesystems. Here's an example: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/mounted-read-write-fat32-partition-suddenly-becomes-read-only-166190/. Unmounting it then fixing it (using `fsck.vfat` in linux or `scandisk` in windows worked for many). Make a copy beforehand.

Comment: Cornielscu: Yes, I found out `fsck.vfat` had to be run many times until all errors were fixed, but forgot to update my question. Only when I looked at certain filenames would the filesystem become read-only, so I guess the driver noticed the corruption and put it in read-only to avoid further dataloss. Add an answer, and I'll accept it.